# Parsing NBA season stats from basketball-reference.com, how to remove html comment tags

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse the miscellaneous stats table from basketball-reference.com (https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_1980.html). However, the table that I would like to parse is inside html comment.

Using the following code

```
html = requests.get("http://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2016.html").content
cleaned_soup = BeautifulSoup(re.sub("<!--|-->","", html))
```

results to the following

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-93508687bbc6> in <module>()
----> 1 cleaned_soup = BeautifulSoup(re.sub("<!--|-->","", html))

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/re.py in sub(pattern, repl, string, count, flags)
    190     a callable, it's passed the Match object and must return
    191     a replacement string to be used."""
--> 192     return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
    193 
    194 def subn(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0):

TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

I am using python3.7.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to use `re` to put all of the HTML inside the comments into your HTML, you could instead use BeautifulSoup to return you just the comments from the HTML. These can then also be parsed using BeautifulSoup to extract any table elements as required, for example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment


html = requests.get("http://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2016.html").content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for comment in soup.find_all(text=lambda t : isinstance(t, Comment)):
    comment_html = BeautifulSoup(comment, "html.parser")

    for table in comment_html.find_all("table"):
        for tr in table.find_all("tr"):
            row = [td.text for td in tr.find_all("td")]
            print(row)
        print()
```

This would give you rows in the tables starting:

```
['Finals', 'Cleveland Cavaliers \nover \nGolden State Warriors\n\xa0(4-3)\n', 'Series Stats']
['\n\n\nGame 1\nThu, June 2\nCleveland Cavaliers\n89@ Golden State Warriors\n104\n\nGame 2\nSun, June 5\nCleveland Cavaliers\n77@ Golden State Warriors\n110\n\nGame 3\nWed, June 8\nGolden State Warriors\n90@ Cleveland Cavaliers\n120\n\nGame 4\nFri, June 10\nGolden State Warriors\n108@ Cleveland Cavaliers\n97\n\nGame 5\nMon, June 13\nCleveland Cavaliers\n112@ Golden State Warriors\n97\n\nGame 6\nThu, June 16\nGolden State Warriors\n101@ Cleveland Cavaliers\n115\n\nGame 7\nSun, June 19\nCleveland Cavaliers\n93@ Golden State Warriors\n89\n\n\n', 'Game 1', 'Thu, June 2', 'Cleveland Cavaliers', '89', '@ Golden State Warriors', '104', 'Game 2', 'Sun, June 5', 'Cleveland Cavaliers', '77', '@ Golden State Warriors', '110', 'Game 3', 'Wed, June 8', 'Golden State Warriors', '90', '@ Cleveland Cavaliers', '120', 'Game 4', 'Fri, June 10', 'Golden State Warriors', '108', '@ Cleveland Cavaliers', '97', 'Game 5', 'Mon, June 13', 'Cleveland Cavaliers', '112', '@ Golden State Warriors', '97', 'Game 6', 'Thu, June 16', 'Golden State Warriors', '101', '@ Cleveland Cavaliers', '115', 'Game 7', 'Sun, June 19', 'Cleveland Cavaliers', '93', '@ Golden State Warriors', '89']
['Game 1', 'Thu, June 2', 'Cleveland Cavaliers', '89', '@ Golden State Warriors', '104']
['Game 2', 'Sun, June 5', 'Cleveland Cavaliers', '77', '@ Golden State Warriors', '110']
['Game 3', 'Wed, June 8', 'Golden State Warriors', '90', '@ Cleveland Cavaliers', '120']
['Game 4', 'Fri, June 10', 'Golden State Warriors', '108', '@ Cleveland Cavaliers', '97']
```

Note: To avoid getting the `cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object`, you could have used `.text` instead of `.content` to pass the string to your regular expression.